# Internet stops working!

Tags: internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu Internet stops working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99476/ubuntu-internet-stops-working)

I have a very big Internet problem in Ubuntu. Whenever I load a web page or download something it will download half of the file and then it will stop downloading. After that the only whey I can fix it is if I diconnect from my wireless access point and then reconnect and start the download again. So how do I fix this? This also happens with Youtube videos.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What happens if you connect an ethernet cable directly to your router?

Comment: I can not connect an enter net cable the reputed is to fire away. Here are system specs http://p.twimg.com/AkTmv2_CAAE3QNf.jpg:large