# Ubuntu Internet stops working

Tags: internet

I have a very big Internet problem in Ubuntu. Whenever I load a web page or download something it will download half of the file and then it will stop downloading. After that the only whey I can fix it is if I diconnect from my wireless access point and then reconnect and start the download again. So how do I fix this? This also happens with Youtube videos.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

try typing this on your terminal - -

```
    sudo dhclient0 wlan0
```

This might solve the problem ..

If not then while your internet is working..
type

```
    lspci
```

in terminal and save it in a file
after you get disconnected try this again and write in a different file

vimdiff to see the device-driver change.. download a set set of drivers accordingly to solve..

Comment: It say dhclient0 cmannd not found

Comment: @iphone4life4, it should be dhclient without the 0. This worked for me, thanks minocha.

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue only on ubuntu? Is it only on this computer?

If the answer is yes to both of these questions, it may be a driver issue. Otherwise it is most likely an internet connection issue.

For best support it would be good if you could give us the name/model of your device to allow us to help you more.

Otherwise, try this in terminal...

```
modprobe -r *driver_name*
```

Then follow these directions to blacklist the module... http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=796831

If you have any issues, you can un-blacklist the module and re-add with

```
modprobe *driver_name*
```